# Can't Get Emacs Going - error: (quote load-path) is not a valid place expression

Tags: macos, debugging, emacs, gdb

I've installed cli Emacs 24.5.1 (via Macports), Aquamacs and Emacs.app on my 2009 Mac Pro running Yosemite (OS X 10.10) to see which (if any) I liked best (I usually use Vim, but I read that you could use Emacs more like an IDE, and set it up to understand Vim keystrokes via the 'evil' package). Unfortunately, they're all giving me the same error on startup:

```
Warning (initialization): An error occurred while loading     `/Users/lachlan/.emacs':

error: (quote load-path) is not a valid place expression
```

There's very little that I can find on Google about this error, and nothing exactly fits my case. My .emacs file is below:

```
1   (add-to-list 'load-path "~/.emacs.d/lisp/")
  1
  2 (require 'undo-tree)
  3
  4 (require 'linum)
  5 (global-linum-mode 1)
  6
  7 (require 'package)
  8 (add-to-list 'package-archives '("melpa" .  "http://melpa.org/packages/"))
  9 (package-initialize)
 10
 11 (push "~/.emacs.d/evil" 'load-path)
 12 (require 'evil)
 13 (evil-mode 1)
 14
```

I don't really know any lisp and, with everything else I'm trying to learn at the moment, I'm rather overloaded and don't want to have to learn lisp just to get the Emacs IDE going. So if you can't really use Emacs without knowing lisp, tell me now and put me out of my misery, and I'll go back to Vim.

All I actually wanted was a gdb or lldb frontend which (amongst other things) disassembles around each line of C/C++ source code (or otherwise connects the two), and runs under OS X. Xcode, CLion, Codeblocks and Codelite don't do it (that I can find), and Emacs was suggested on this site as being able to do it, so I thought I'd try it. If it doesn't do this, could somebody tell me so I can go back to Vim a wiser, more solemn and chastened touch-typist.

Comment: If your end goal is to just use Emacs for a gdb frontend, and not necessarily get into the details of using Emacs, you might try one of the starter kits.  For example, Spacemacs uses vim-like keybindings by default.  I've never used it but I've heard good things.  You should also try using `gdb` by itself, though a frontend is admittedly much nicer for many debugging tasks.

Comment: Thanks, jpkotta, I hadn't heard of it. I'm just downloading it now, and will try it. I do use gdb by itself alongside Vim, actually (well, I use it with peda, but that's just like using it by itself, but with more contextual information). It's just that, as a learning tool for assembly etc., I wanted to sometimes use a debugger which disassembles around (or otherwise associates the resulting lines of assembly with) each line of C/C++ code, because when I'm doing anything object-oriented in C++, I get lost in the disassembly and can't find my way around, and could use some guidance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is on line 11, where `load-path` is quoted but shouldn't be. The expression

```
(push "~/.emacs.d/evil" 'load-path)
```

should instead be

```
(push "~/.emacs.d/evil" load-path)
```

Comment: Yes, but please say *why*: The second argument to `push` must be a list, not a symbol. The value of variable `load-path` is a list. The value of `'load-path` is a symbol, not a list.

Comment: Thank you Steve, Drew, it works fine now, including the evil keybindings! Whee! Now I just have to figure out how to get it to be a frontend for gdb. Ho hum...